# jQuery remove an object and replace in same spot

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I go about removing an object say from an unordered list and add it to another list while keeping its location?  I know i can set the original item to hide() but then that leaves a small space where the item use to appear.  Say i have a list A and B, if a user clicks on an item in A it needs to be added to B and removed from A.  If they now click on a button to remove it from B and back to A, i want to have it displayed in the same spot it originally did.  I know i can add it via append() but that won't put it in the same location.  Thoughts anyone?

Comment: Sample markup could help us visualize this better. You also need to accept answers to your previous questions (use the checkmark).

Comment: Usually hiding it would not leave a gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use .clone? so:

```
<ul id="firstlist">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>

<ul id="secondlist">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

the jquery:

```
var object = $('#firstlist > li :last ').clone();
$('#secondlist').append(object);
$('#firstlist > li :last ').destroy();
```

Obviously you can swap this round to add it to the first list, but to get the position you could use a number of ways, I would probably do:

```
$('#firstlist').children('li').each(function(i){

});
```

and use "i" to get the position. you can append after a given object to so:

```
$('#firstlist').children('li').each(function(i)
 { if(i== 4){ $(this).append(object).after(this) }
```

Comment: Use the `{}` button above the editor. Or select the text you want to convert and press ctrl+k.

Answer (score 1):

Heres my bid:

- Allows you to click an element in **list-1** and it will hide *that* instance, and append a clone to **list-2**.
- Clicking the item in **list-2** will return it back to **list-1**, in the *same position* it came from.
- Clicking "original elements" in **list-2** *will not* copy over to **list-1**.

HTML:

```
<ul id="list-1">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
<ul id="list-2"></ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
var $list1 = $('#list-1');
var $list2 = $('#list-2');
$list1.children('li').each(function(i,e){
    var ulId = $(this).closest('ul').attr('id');
    $(this).attr('li-id',ulId+'_'+i);
}).click(function(e){
    if ($list2.find('li[li-id="'+$(this).attr('li-id')+'"]').length == 0){
        var liClone = $(this).clone();
        liClone.click(function(e){
            var elId = $(this).attr('li-id');
            $list1.find('li[li-id="'+elId+'"]').show();
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $list2.append(liClone);
    }
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Fiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/vgx23/1/