# How can I re-attach element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I am trying to re-attach an element when it has been detached from the DOM however I can't seem to find an easy solution to this.

```
$(document).on('click', '#emailEnquiryPreferred', function () {
  $('.form-group-timepicker').fadeOut(300, function(){ $(this).detach(); });
});
```

As you can see with the following code I am detaching it however with another click event **I would like to reattach it to the same position**, how can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Through any DOM insertion function -- `append()`, for instance.

Comment: Why do you detach it? If it is hidden, does it still bother you?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817795/jquery-remove-an-object-and-replace-in-same-spot

Answer (score 1):

Keep it as variable before attaching it:

```
var $detachedElement;
$(document).on('click', '#emailEnquiryPreferred', function () {
  $('.form-group-timepicker').fadeOut(300, function(){
    $detachedElement = $(this); 
    $(this).detach(); 
  });
});
```

Now when you need to re-attach it simple use `$detachedElement` variable ...

Here is a full sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var $detachedElement;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#id2').on('click', function() {
                $('#div').append($detachedElement);
            })

            $("p#id1").click(function() {
                $detachedElement = $(this).detach();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="div" style="border: red solid 1px">
        <p id="id1">Detach Me!</p>
    </div>

    <p id="id2">Re-attach it!</p>

</body>

</html>
```